# curl on Windows 10: "invalid character in header"

Tags: windows, curl

I am trying to use the curl example below on Windows 10 from [REST API Home Assistant Developer Docs](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/external_api_rest/).

```json
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ABCDEFGH" \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -d '{"entity_id": "switch.christmas_lights"}' \
       http://localhost:8123/api/services/switch/turn_on
```

Below, is my actual command-line (escaping the double-quotes for Windows):

```html
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI5OTc5ZDUwZjA2MDk0YmQ1YTBkYjkyYmQ5MjEyYWZkNyIsImlhdCI6MTU4Nzc5MzI4NywiZXhwIjoxOTAzMTUzMjg3fQ.8sjGRXL1spXguuRnp795049zdCFcOtraCiDjC61UkWQ" -H "{\"Content-Type: application/json\"}" -d "{\"entity_id\": \"light.media_room_light\"}" http://homeassistant.local:8123/api/services/switch/turn_on
```

It responds with the below error message.  I'm using the curl.exe I downloaded from

`invalid character in header`

I downloaded **curl.exe** from: 
    [https://curl.haxx.se/windows/](http://%20%20%20%20https://curl.haxx.se/windows/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got your MIME Content-Type header mixed up with the json encoded data field.

Instead of this:

```
-H "{\"Content-Type: application/json\"}"
```

This:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Flattened into a single line:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI5OTc5ZDUwZjA2MDk0YmQ1YTBkYjkyYmQ5MjEyYWZkNyIsImlhdCI6MTU4Nzc5MzI4NywiZXhwIjoxOTAzMTUzMjg3fQ.8sjGRXL1spXguuRnp795049zdCFcOtraCiDjC61UkWQ" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"entity_id\": \"light.media_room_light\"}" http://homeassistant.local:8123/api/services/switch/turn_on
```